# The page numbering on SO is not conducive to bookmarking reading progress

Tags: discussion, feature-request, pagination

Since the newest page is always "`1`", this means that the number of any single page in a set of pages is constantly increasing. This is especially pertinent when using the "Newest" tab.

This means that if I'm reading through the pages for a certain tag, I cannot bookmark the page I am on currently, since the page number will change as questions get added.

It'd be more conducive to careful perusal of questions to have the oldest page have the number "`1`". That way you could bookmark your progress on any set of paged pages.

*Are there any work arounds for this? How does everyone handle reading through pages for tags and such?*

Comment: I just rely on cookies, myself. Clear my data prior to starting a big job, so that every single post is "unvisited". Then I start from the oldest and move forwards. Record the page when I stop, and when I get back, just take the extra time to relocate myself to where my "visited" links end. An "oldest" navigation setting may help alleviate this, though, rather than going from "newest" in reverse.

Comment: I like the "oldest" navigation idea.

Comment: @Grace: That's browser history, not cookies.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's just me, but I don't find it worthwhile to read all questions in a certain tag, especially a big, popular tag.  Most questions are [crud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law) and not worth your time.

What I do instead is mostly follow blogs plus Twitter, with some following of a few users (through per-user feeds though usually just being more likely to click through if I see their name).  However, I do use a few per-tag feeds (low-volume tags only) and a reader that keeps track of which I've read.  For example, I see you like [[php]](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php&sort=newest).

Comment: And FYI: Make sure to include a link to your [micro-]blog (if it's programming-related even a little) in your bio.  If I've read just one really good post from you, I'll probably subscribe and see how useful it is.

Comment: I like the rss feed option, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wfaulk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132601/wfaulk)'s [greasemonkey script to mark unread questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations/25927#25927).

Comment: I'll try it.... At first try it doesn't work (I use Chrome extensions)... but I'll play around with it.