# Is it possible to sort questions by oldest?

Tags: support, sorting, question-lists

On a site I have a custom filter that lists unanswered questions tagged with my watched tags. There are 500+ questions and I want to review them from time to time.

If I sort by newest, the pages will eventually shift and I'll lose track. I would like to be able to bookmark the page at least. Is there a way to sort by oldest?

I see the following similar question, but it's too old and doesn't answer my question.

[The page numbering on SO is not conducive to bookmarking reading progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63084)

Comment: If you use search, you can limit it to posts created before today so that you can go to the last page when sorting by newest and not be disrupted by new posts. But this doesn’t prevent people from deleting a lot of newer posts and messing up the page number that way.

Comment: @Laurel That solution works well, especially when I exclude last few days from search. Thanks.